# Let $\Omega = (\Omega_E,\Omega_K)$ be a connected graph. Proof that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ contain at least one common corner.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $\Omega = (\Omega_E,\Omega_K)$ be a connected graph, and let moreover $\omega_1 \in \Omega^{l+1}_E$ and $\omega \in \Omega^{l+1}_E$ two corner-simple paths of maximum possible length $l$ (i.e., there are no corner-simple paths in $\Omega$ with length $> l$). Proof that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ contain at least one common corner.

Coherence is a mathematical term from graph theory. A graph is called connected if its nodes are connected in pairs by a sequence of edges. A path $\omega = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n) \in \Omega^n_E $ in a (simple) graph $(\Omega_K, \Omega_E)$ is called corner simple, if $\alpha_i \neq \alpha_j $ for $1 \leq i < j < n$.

At the moment I am studying for my upcoming exam and while working on the supplementary material I came across this task for which I unfortunately have no Idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the corner and coherence terminology.  But I think you want to show that if you take two paths of the same maximum length $l$, then there is at least one vertex that is on both paths.  Try to assume that these paths are vertex-disjoint, and try to form a longer path.